# Error during installation of absl-py version 0.8.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, absl-py

The command

```
pip install absl-py==0.8.1
```

generates the following error:

```
Collecting absl-py==0.8.1
  Using cached absl-py-0.8.1.tar.gz (103 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\Users\z0017fjy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "c:\Users\z0017fjy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "c:\Users\z0017fjy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\z0017fjy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-d9eghk5s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\z0017fjy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-d9eghk5s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\z0017fjy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-d9eghk5s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 488, in run_setup
          self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\z0017fjy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-d9eghk5s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 34, in <module>
      RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.
      [end of output]
```

According to the output,

> Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required

My

```
python --version
```

is

```
3.11.2
```

Which should actually meet the 3.4+ requirement.

So what could be the problem?

Comment: My general solution in these scenarios is to use a virtual environment with the right version of Python. Also update ``pip``.